# Is it possible to mock android services under unit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-service

I'm trying to write unit tests for my android application and I want to mock my service class. I want to test some error behaviors in the service, such as connection errors or file not found.

To simplify my question, I started a new Android Project and created an Activity and a Service class:

**MyAndroidProjectActivity.java**

```
package br.org.venturus.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import br.org.venturus.android.service.MyService;

public class MyAndroidProjectActivity extends Activity {
    private MyService service;
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            service = ((MyService.MyBinder) binder).getService();

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            service = null;
        }
    };
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        {
            Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            startService(service);

            bindService(service, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // stop MyService
        {
            Intent svc = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            stopService(svc);
        }
    }

    public void doChange(View view) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);

        tv.setText(service.getNewString());
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
package br.org.venturus.android.service;

import br.org.venturus.android.R;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private IBinder binder;

    public MyService() {
        this.binder = new MyBinder();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    public String getNewString() {
        return getString(R.string.change);
    }

}
```

And I created a new Android Test Project with this unit class:

**MyAndroidProjectActivityTest.java**

```
package br.org.venturus.android.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.UiThreadTest;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import br.org.venturus.android.MyAndroidProjectActivity;
import br.org.venturus.android.R;

public class MyAndroidProjectActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyAndroidProjectActivity> {

    private MyAndroidProjectActivity mActivity;
    private TextView tvHello;
    private Button btChange;

    public MyAndroidProjectActivityTest() {
        super("br.org.venturus.android", MyAndroidProjectActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        // Get the activity and components
        {
            mActivity = this.getActivity();
            tvHello = (TextView) mActivity
                    .findViewById(br.org.venturus.android.R.id.tvHello);
            btChange = (Button) mActivity
                    .findViewById(br.org.venturus.android.R.id.btChange);
        }

    }

    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(tvHello);
        assertNotNull(btChange);
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testChangeButton() {
        assertEquals(tvHello.getText(), getActivity().getString(R.string.hello));
        btChange.performClick();
        assertEquals(tvHello.getText(), getActivity()
                .getString(R.string.change));
    }
}
```

When I run the unit tests, the pre conditions and the change button tests are fine. What I want to do, for instance, is to create a MyServiceMock and override the MyService.getNewString to return other value, and mock this object in the test.

Something like this:

**MyServiceMock.java**

```
package br.org.venturus.android.test.service;

import br.org.venturus.android.service.MyService;

public class MyServiceMock extends MyService {
    @Override
    public String getNewString() {      
        return "This is the new value!";
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I was not mocking the unit under test, I wanted to mock other components that are not the scope of my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and I think the example of the *MyServiceMock.java* above is also an alternative.

There are a few mocking frameworks out there that you can use for this.

I have some experience with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

You can just mock the MyService class and specify that when the getNewString method is called, return a string "This is the new value!".

```
MyService myServiceMock = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);

Mockito.doReturn("This is the new value!").when(myServiceMock).getNewString();
```

You can also use the *Mockito.doThrow()* method to throw an exception when a mock method is called:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mockedList).clear();

//following throws RuntimeException:
mockedList.clear();
```

Comment: Setting expectations is the easy part, but how do you replace the service declared in the manifest started by the framework and all the binding lifecycle with the mock object you created: `myServiceMock`?

Comment: Exactly... Anybody with tips on how to replace the reular service with mocked service? Maybe by using dependency injection?