# Android - make activity use service mock

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mocking, android-service

In this thread it's explained how to mock android service:
[Is it possible to mock android services under unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583697/is-it-possible-to-mock-android-services-under-unit-tests)

But how can I make my activity use this mock instead of real service?
I'm not using any DI frameworks.

Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could give this 1000 upvotes. The problem is that all you find on the web seems to be about Mockito and Dagger2 which is not really helpful in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something, if not DI, just make some Factory class that in test returns a mock instead of real instance.

Comment: But service instance is obtained in onServiceConnected() callback, so I can't simply create one in a factory...  Maybe you could give me some link to an example (i think it's a common issue).

Comment: @user2203031 Here is the first link when searching for 'android service mock testing': http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/service_testing.html

Comment: @verybadalloc this link is about service testing, while my question is about activity testing (using mocked service).

Comment: you can trigger whatever you want via mocking, and because you test the activity why do you care?

Comment: Listen, Service is not like a common class which I can simply inject using setters ( something like activity.setService(mockService) ).
Service's instance is obtained in onServiceConnected() callback.


I know how this injection can be done using RoboGuice, but I think it's an overkill for my application.

Comment: So don't, just use the real service if it's a major pain, or create a subclass and override whatever you need for isolation.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't inject a fake service, but use the real one and override it's components?

Comment: Yes, it;ll make your testing much simple

Comment: @ChenKinnrot: What is DI?